# Import another modules is not working after updated the android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated android studio to "Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1".
After this update, I created a new module and I want to add another module into the newly created module but I have an error. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

**we can use both, api() or implementation().**

implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":components:preference")))
or
implementation(project(":components:preference"))

[https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#:~:text=implementation(project(%22%3Adomain%22))](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#:%7E:text=implementation(project(%22%3Adomain%22)))